# Manjaro KDE Установка и удаление программ (пакеты не найдены)

Tags: linux, app, kde, manjaro

[image: Пакеты не найдены]

**Linux Manjaro KDE Plasma**

Во встроенном ПО '*Установка и удаление программ*' не отображаются приложения!

Пишет: '*Пакеты не найдены*'

**Посдкажите какие пакеты ему требуются и как их установить?**

Comment: https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Using_Manjaro_for_Beginners

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в терминале написать:

```
pamac search -a package_name
```